# Where to put generic functions?

Tags: php, magento-1, best-practice

I have a collection of generic functions in my Magento project. Right now they're in single PHP file, and it's being called with a `require_once` in each phtml that needs it.

I don't like it and I feel there's got to be a better place for them.

What's the Magento way of dealing with this? A module just for these function? Most of them call `Mage::app`, but not all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in your question that you're using `Mage::app()` so I'm assuming it's Magento 1.x we're talking about.

Generic functions in Magento 1 are mostly done with a concept called *Helpers*. The concept is simple, create a module with a helper (there's plenty of information out there on how to create a Magento Module with a helper, like [this article](https://gielberkers.com/create-magento-module/) for example).

In this helper you can add your public methods. For example:

```
<?php
class Example_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function sum($a, $b) {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

You can use them in your templates (or anywhere else) with `Mage::helper()`. For example:

```
echo Mage::helper('my_module')->sum(10, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Helper** for your auxiliary functions. In Magento, you can put your methods in Helper that you have no idea where to put them or if you need to call them in a lot of different places (models, controllers, templates).

Creating a Magento Helper is quite easy. In your module’s `../etc/config.xml` file, declare the new helper class under  as follows:

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        ...
        <helpers>
            <common> <!-- helper name -->
                <class>Vendor_Common_Helper</class> <!-- declaration of helper class -->
            </common>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then creates the folder and the file `app/code/local/Vendor/Common/Helper/Data.php`.

```
class Vendor_Common_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
   public function double($nbr)
   {
        return $nbr*2;
   }
}
```

Now we can use this helper function anywhere in Magento like this:

```
Mage::helper('common')->double(5);
```